# How to create many to one relation with cross filter direction is both?

Tags: relation, powerbi

[image]I'm newbie on power bi, I tried to create a many to one relation with cross filter, direction is both.

How can I do? I tried create to relation with

```
Manage Relationships -> New... -> "choose my table"
```

but drop down from "Cross filter direction" is grey.

Comment: Make sure you selected tables you want to create relationship between, and also the columns

Comment: yes, i'm sure have selected tables at want to create relationship

Comment: i import data with DirectQuery, if this effect?

Comment: That does appear to be the reason - [semi relevant](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/11434623-allow-bi-directional-filtering-for-directquery-rep).